# Intel Rapid Start Driver Reinstallation doesn't work?

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, lenovo-laptop, intel-rapid-start

I recently had to reformat my entire drive and reinstall Windows 7. Something that bothers me is that when I was downloading the Intel Rapid Start driver (I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y480, and it comes standard with the Rapid Start) and tried to install it, the installer claimed that my system did not meet the requirements in order to install, when it was previously installed by the OEM.

My startup times have increased from 21 seconds to log-in screen to 50 seconds.

Please help...

Specs:

Lenovo Ideapad Y480

Intel Core i7-3610 Ivy Bridge (quad-core)

Nvidia Geforce 640M LE with 2gb VRAM

8GB RAM

1TB hard drive, 32 GB SSD (OEM installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a bit late here in helping, but typically Lenovo provides their own versions of drivers. So if you got the driver from the intel website, it won't work, but if you get it from Lenovo at http://support.lenovo.com for you model it will work fine.

For example, I just did the same thing you did (reinstall Windows on a U410 and the driver on lenovo support worked fine!

Installing RapidStart is not as easy as that though. Make sure you [follow the instructions here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.intel.com%2Fsupport%2Fmotherboards%2Fdesktop%2Fsb%2Frapid_start_technology_user_guide.pdf&ei=IkNKUOmSNcjj0QGAvoGoBg&usg=AFQjCNGw7Nj_6cbq5tJ0Gi0LmHsNTCF4XQ&sig2=RwFatdzeL329tMzS6ORlpw) to get it right.

Comment: Yeah. you were a bit late. I have already installed Windows on the HD and don't want to reinstall everything. But thank you for linking the documents, approving your answer now.